# isnumeric function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table with data a mixture of alpha and numeric, I'm trying to find the way to extract value only if it's numeric

```
PSDcode2:
========
631302
631308
631309
631301
 STATE
 STATE
ON TWP
```

My select statement will work just fine, but I just is there better way of doing this? thanks

```
case when PS.PSDcode2 in (' STATE','ON TWP') then 'NULL' else PS.PSDcode2  end as PSDcode2,
```

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: I don't get it - you put the answer to your question in the title...

Comment: sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with `NOT LIKE` approach it works well for any data

```
Select * [Table_Name] WHERE PSDcode2 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: OLD: 
case when PS.PSDcode2 in (' STATE','ON TWP') then 'NULL' else PS.PSDcode2  end as PSDcode2
NEW:
case when PS.PSDcode2 NOT like '%[^0-9]%' then PS.PSDcode2 else 'NULL'  end as PSDcode2

Answer (score 1):

For SQL:-

```
SELECT PSDcode2 FROM [Table_Name] WHERE ISNUMERIC([PSDcode2]) = 1
```

check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

OR

```
Select PSDcode2 [Table_Name] WHERE PSDcode2 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND [PSDcode2]!=''
```

For Oracle:-

```
SELECT PSDcode2 FROM [Table_Name] WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(PSDcode2,'^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Comment: I can count on one hand the number of databases that support `isnumeric()`.  The question doesn't specify the database.